Skaffold error using VSCode and Google Cloud SDK on Windows 11
I am using:

Windows 11
VS Code
Google Cloud SDK 486.0.0 with Skaffold 2.11.1

I have the stupidest of errors and cannot figure it out. It's worth noting this worked 6 months ago. I haven't touched it since, and now it doesn't work...
Retrieving builders.
Getting Gcloud Login State.
Using current GCP Project "abc"
Checking Cloud Run API status.
Getting Cloud Run Services for project "abc".
Executing Skaffold build.
Running skaffold command: cmd.exe /c C:\Users\someuser\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\skaffold.exe init --artifact {"image":"gcr.io/abc/authzen-xacml-interop","builder":"Docker","payload":{"path":"Dockerfile"}} --skip-deploy --filename C:\Users\someuser\AppData\Local\Temp\cloud-code-cloud-run-QG2PY1\skaffold.yaml --force
'C:\Users\someuser\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Failed to build the app. Error: Failed to create skaffold configuration. Error: 'C:\Users\someuser\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Obviously, the whitespace is an issue. In Windows, if you do not wrap the command in double quotes" it considers the value as 2 values so the error makes sense. But the question is why? I am using the extension provided by Google and I cannot find any setting that would let me control its behavior. Short of reinstalling on a path that has no whitespace, what can I do?

